# Producing a "self contained" flextable to use in latex

Tags: r, pdf, latex, png, flextable

I'm need to generate a "bunch" of tables in R that must be included in a Latex document.

I can create very nice tables using flextable... but I am not able to generate ANY format that can then be inserted in (multiple places) in a latex document.

The problem is that any method that I try will add extra "margins" (like in pdf... prints a table to a full page) or has some limitation (like png).

Does any ne has a solution, either using directly an RScript or trough knitting R-Markdown?

(Note: The solution of producing the whole latex doc in RMarkdown is Not feasible.)

Just to present an example. I would like this would produce a Full-Page (with dimensions of the table... not A4) of the table.

Thank you very much for your Help :).

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)
```

```{r}
ft <- flextable(head(airquality))
ft <- autofit(ft)
theme_vader(ft)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `standalone` class (a bit of extra space is still there, but much less than a full page):

````
---
documentclass: standalone
classoption: varwidth
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(flextable)
```

```{r}
ft <- flextable(head(airquality))
ft <- autofit(ft)
theme_vader(ft)
```
````

[image]